# dnsbl blacklist query not working on Linux server

Tags: php, dnsbl

I'm having a problem is that if I run my this script on local wampserver then it show the correct result if it already blacklisted but if I run on my server etc... /usr/bin/php path-to-phpscript.php then it shows that this ip is blacklisted in all bls names which is not correct.

```
<?php

$bls = array("b.barracudacentral.org",
"bl.score.senderscore.com",
"pbl.spamhaus.org",
"sbl.spamhaus.org",
"xbl.spamhaus.org",
"zen.spamhaus.org",
"dbl.spamhaus.org",
"sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org",
);


$ip = '62.213.183.192';

if ( isset($ip)) {

if ( filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) || false === filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {

    if (false === filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL  )) { 
        $iptosplit = gethostbyname($ip);
    }
    else {
        $iptosplit = $ip;
    }
    $splitip = explode (".", $iptosplit);
    $iptolookup = "$splitip[3].$splitip[2].$splitip[1].$splitip[0]";
    $counter=1;
    $blList = array();
    foreach ( $bls as $rbl ) {
        //echo "<tr>";
        $rbllookup = $iptolookup.".".$rbl;
        $lookup = gethostbyname($rbllookup);

        if ( $lookup != $rbllookup || $lookup == $ip) {
            $qtxtresult = dns_get_record("$rbllookup", DNS_TXT);
            if ( ! isset($qtxtresult[0]['txt']) ) {
                $qtxtresult[0]['txt'] = "";
            }
            $blList[$counter]=$ip.' is listed in ('.$rbl.')';
            echo '...........Listed in -'.$rbl.'<br />';                
        }
        echo str_repeat(" ", 24), "\n";

        $counter++;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Which name server are you using when it fails? vs. name server when it works? I've noticed with my rbl lookups for my email server that the ones I'm using block most common/isp/google/cloudfare DNS servers due to load and caching... changing to a cache-only bind9 server on the mail server fixed it

Answer (score 0):

This code has been included into a source snippet of dnsbl.tornevall.org (Downloadable through https://dnsbl.tornevall.org/download/) and returns an array if the ip is blacklisted. It also supports ipv6. If it is blacklisted, $result[3] has a positive value which is a bitmask, and the bitmask value depends on that type of blacklist-type the ip has been marked as.

In this example I'm using a random ip I know is blacklisted in the domain. Unfortunately, the script does not support TXT-lookups, but this script is also very basic if you only need something that prevents connections from blacklisted ip-addresses.

```
function rblresolve ($ip = '', $rbldomain = '')
{
        if (!$ip) {return false;}                       // No data should return nothing
        if (!$rbldomain) {return false;}        // No rbl = ignore

        // Old function (during betatesting we want to keep those rows so we can fall back if something fails)
        // $returnthis = explode('.', gethostbyname(implode('.', array_reverse(explode('.', $ip))) . '.' . $rbldomain));           // Not ipv6-compatible!
        // if (implode(".", $returnthis) != implode('.', array_reverse(explode('.', $ip))) . '.' . $rbldomain) {return $returnthis;} else {return false;}

        // New ipv6-compatible function
        $returnthis = (long2ip(ip2long($ip)) != "0.0.0.0" ? explode('.', gethostbyname(implode('.', array_reverse(explode('.', $ip))) . '.' . $rbldomain)) : explode(".", gethostbyname(v6arpa($ip) . "." . $rbldomain)));
        // 127-bug-checking
            if (implode(".", $returnthis) != (long2ip(ip2long($ip)) != "0.0.0.0" ? implode('.', array_reverse(explode('.', $ip))) . '.' . $rbldomain : v6arpa($ip) . "." . $rbldomain)) {return $returnthis;} else {return false;}
}

function v6arpa($ip)
{
        $unpack = unpack('H*hex', inet_pton($ip));
        $hex = $unpack['hex'];
        return implode('', array_reverse(str_split($hex)));
}

$result = rblresolve("117.197.11.203", "dnsbl.tornevall.org");
print_r($result);
```

Returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 127
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 67
```

)